What is the difference between OleInitialize and CoInitializeEx
Based on the document of OleInitialize (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ole2/nf-ole2-oleinitialize), it said OleInitialize will call CoInitializeEx internally.
Then what is the difference between
OleInitialize(NULL);

and
CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);


OleInitialize initializes OLE. OLE depends on COM, so first it initializes COM, and then it initializes OLE after that. If you just do CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED); then you have initialized COM, but not OLE.

@RaymondChen, I want to automate Excel with Multi Threaded Apartment(MTA), does CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED) enough or I need more codes to intiailize OLE?

You'll have to check the documentation to see what the requirements are for the Excel automation interface you're using. (You never said which automation interface you're using. There are several.)
